# word embedding of a lstm sequence

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, gensim, word-embedding

Suppose, I have a Seq2Seq model. I want to have the Embedding layer in this model.

Based on my research I can do it in three ways:

1. train a word embedding separately on my data set or download a pre-trained word embedding, then use the weights of those embedding as the weight of the words in my data set. So here I do not need to have an embedding layer at all, I just load the weights of the already trained words into the words in my data set.
2. I create an embedding layer and set the trainable true, so not only I have an embedding, but also, that embedding will be trained based on my task
3. I create an Embedding layer, load already trained weights, and set trainable False. in this case, the weights will not get updated.

(please correct me if Im wrong).

I have used the `first approach`. I want to know what will be the interpretation of the output of this code:

```
model_wv = Word2Vec.load("word2vec_50d_7w")
embeddings = np.zeros((len(model_wv.wv.vocab), emb_dim))
for i in range(len(model_wv.wv.vocab)):
    # print(i)
    embedding_vector = model_wv.wv[model_wv.wv.index2word[i]]
    if embedding_vector is not None:
        embeddings[i] = embedding_vector

print(embeddings[[1,2,3],[3,4,1]])
```

this is the output:

```
[-0.01566689 -1.36469996  0.59684211]
```

consider this `[1,2,3],[3,4,1]` as two sequence with `length=3`.

I was thinking we use word embedding in lstm to transform each word of the sequence into an embedding. I expected to see `two vectors` and `three items` in each vector.

The embedding is the word2vec in gensim,

Appreciate it if someone shed light on it where I am getting lost?

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretations on the three variants of setting up the embedding layer is exactly correct as what I understand.

There are two major transfer learning techniques.

1. Using the pre-learned model as a **feature-vector**. In your case, the word2vec model would be used as a lookup service to pre-process/convert tokens to ids and then to embedding vectors. These embedding vectors become the actual feature when you train your own model. (this is your #1)
2. Using a **fine-tuning** approach. Here you can choose to either continue training the pre-learned model (setting trainable=True) or fix the prelearned model (setting trainable=False). There could benefits in either approach. (This is your #2 and #3)

(#1 and #3) produce similar result regarding quality from my experience. 
If you own a decent amount of training data, fine-tuning with trainable=True (#2) would be the best approach from my experience.

You problem here is a numpy issue. you probably should say,

```
print(embeddings[[1,2,3]], embeddings[[3,4,1]])
```

Otherwise the [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing) is not working as you expected.

```
embeddings[[1,2,3],[3,4,1]]
```

This actually lookups the rows with indices 1, 2, 3 and get the column with indices 3, 4, 1 respectively. In other words, it picks up

```
column 3 for row 1
column 4 for row 2
column 1 for row 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming the explanations, plus clarifying the numpy slicing problem. Do you have any idea when usually we use each approach? specially case 1 and three is kind of confusing for me.

Comment: Sure. In your case, you always want to get the entire embedding dimension.  You would not need any slicing on the column dimension (the embedding dimension). So when indexing, supply with row indices (this is your token ids)  is sufficient for looking up purpose.

Comment: What about for training aspect?

Comment: That's a different story. After you lookup the entire embedding vector, operating with a sub-range is definitely ok. But at looking up, you still don't need any slicing. Feel free to choose any convolutional operation on either the sequence dimension and/or the embedding dimension (though not very common on NLP problem).

Comment: ahh, I misunderstood your question. I will add some edits to my answer.